# Why do I get different output from Reactive Sink

Tags: java, reactive-programming, flux

For the following code

```
 Sinks.Many<Integer> replaySink = Sinks.many().replay().all();
      
        Runnable r = () -> {
            Double f1 = Math.random() *100;
            Integer k = f1.intValue() ;

            replaySink.emitNext(k , Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST);
        };
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                service.submit(r);
        }


       replaySink.asFlux().
       log().
        subscribe(System.out::println);
```

I receieve the expected outcome : ( 10 random digits)
13
45
66
..
all together 10 entries
However when I cnange the fixSizeThreadPool to something greater than 1 I receive less than 10 entries in the output, say for poolsize of 2 i get 9 , for poolsize of 5 I get 5 ,and for pool size of 10 just one entry
I suspect that for the pool size of one everything happens on the same thread and therefore I get all my runnable adding value to the sink, all on the same thread, but when the poolsize is greater than 1 , then multiple threads are running and somehow they are not adding to the sink.
However from reference documentation of Reactive:

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#sinks
It looks like multiple threads shall be adding values to Sink in this way.

Comment: Looks like I might have figured this out: if I change the code to replaySink.emitNext(k, Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.busyLooping(Duration.ofSeconds(2)));  I get all the values, so it looks like in the orginal exxample emit next would experience concurrenxy issue and tried to add value to the sync from multiple threads simulaneuolsy and failded, ( that is why it worked on the single thread, bit the more threads added cause the inerfearance, busy looping solves this